# Как с помощью Python переименовать группу файлов по маске?

Tags: python

Я только только начал изучать программирование и столкнулся с определенной задачей. Есть множество файлов названных по принципу "артикул(состоящий из разного количества знаков)#main#номер" и еще несколько файлов к нему названых по принципу "артикул(состоящий из разного количества знаков)#more#номер+1". Мне на по итогу нужно получить "артикул_1 - для #main# (это необходимый минимум). В идеале еще для #more# - артикул_2, артикул_3 и до окончания #more#.

Пытался для #main#:

```
import os
import pathlib
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Роман\\Desktop\\test")
path = pathlib.Path("C:\\Users\\Роман\\Desktop\\test")
for i in path.glob(r'*#main#'):
    new_name = str(i) + "_1.jpg"
    path.rename(new_name)
```

Comment: ваше попытка решения задачи где?

Comment: Добавил, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Пытался и что вышло? Ты в коде не то переименовываешь. Посмотри, что у тебя path.

Answer (score 0):

Лично мне нехватает пару примеров файла и каков конечный результат.
Из описания я бы начал с регулярных выражений. Но с примером было бы интересно.
Если в названии присутствует "#" то можно получать название файла и сплитить по этому знаку и дергать позиции, которые нужны.
Если же название выглядит так. EFJWQFOOasdfa5151+1.
Можно регулярным выражением сделать шаблон.

Comment: Пример выглядит так: 00VZ701rerZ1#main#511417, 00VZ701rerZ1#more#511418 -  конечный результат 00VZ701rerZ1_1 и 00VZ701rerZ1_2 соответственно. Понимаю, что задаю простой и очевидный вопрос, однако мне очень нужна помощь, в решении этой задачи.

Comment: @РоманШад чтобы получить помощь, желательно отвечать на уточняющие вопросы.

Comment: Вас устроит такое решение?

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import os

folder_path = "/home/jung/work/text/folder_test/"

def take_name_files():
    return os.listdir(folder_path)


def rename_files(files_names):
    repeat_names = {}
    for name in files_names:
        list_name = name.split("#")
        if "main" in list_name[1]:
            old_path = os.path.join(folder_path, name)
            new_name = "#".join([(list_name[0]+"_1"),list_name[1],list_name[2]])
            new_path = os.path.join(folder_path, new_name)
            os.rename(old_path, new_path)
            print(new_path)
        elif "more" in list_name[1]:
            if list_name[0] in repeat_names:
                repeat_names[list_name[0]] += 1
                temp_name = f"{list_name[0]}_{repeat_names[list_name[0]]}" 
                old_path = os.path.join(folder_path, name)
                new_name = "#".join([temp_name,list_name[1],list_name[2]])
                new_path = os.path.join(folder_path, new_name)
                os.rename(old_path, new_path)
            else:
                repeat_names[list_name[0]] = 1    
                temp_name = f"{list_name[0]}_{repeat_names[list_name[0]]}" 
                old_path = os.path.join(folder_path, name)
                new_name = "#".join([temp_name,list_name[1],list_name[2]])
                new_path = os.path.join(folder_path, new_name)
                os.rename(old_path, new_path)            


def main():
    
    files_names =take_name_files()
    rename_files(files_names)


main()
```

```
jung@workstation:~/work/text/folder_test$ ls -l 
итого 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 00VZ701dsrZ1#main#511417.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 00VZ701rerZ1#main#511417.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:32 00VZ701rerZ1#more#511420.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:33 00VZ701rerZ1#more#511423.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 10VZ701dsrZ1#main#511417.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 13VZ701dsrZ1#main#511417.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 15VZ701dsrZ1#main#511417.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 15VZ701dsrZ1#more#511417.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 15VZ701dsrZ1#more#511418.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 15VZ701dsrZ1#more#511419.txt
jung@workstation:~/work/text/folder_test$ ls -l 
итого 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 00VZ701dsrZ1_1#main#511417.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 00VZ701rerZ1_1#main#511417.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:32 00VZ701rerZ1_1#more#511420.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:33 00VZ701rerZ1_2#more#511423.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 10VZ701dsrZ1_1#main#511417.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 13VZ701dsrZ1_1#main#511417.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 15VZ701dsrZ1_1#main#511417.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 15VZ701dsrZ1_1#more#511419.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 15VZ701dsrZ1_2#more#511418.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jung jung 0 авг 25 13:25 15VZ701dsrZ1_3#more#511417.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот решение, согласно вашим замечаниям.

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
result_list = []
output_s = "00VZ701rerZ1#main#511417"
split_s = output_s.split("#")
#тут в range второй цифрой пишете значение сколько на выходе хвостов надо быть _*. Только +1
for num in range(1, 3):
    result_list.append(f"{split_s[0]}_{num}")
print(result_list)
```

Comment: Какое же это решение? Нужно файлы переименовать, а список создать

Comment: Ну критиковать, это хорошо. Напишите весь код со всеми нюансами. Возможными повторами исключениями и т.д.